# Spring Integration @Scheduled alternative for cron expression with 7 fields and zone parameter

Tags: xml, spring, cron, spring-integration

@Scheduled doesn't take 7 fields anymore. What are the alternatives if I need the year field for the cron expression? I looked and saw Quartz cron trigger takes in 7 fields, but not sure if it'll work with spring integration inbound adapters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right: there is no year field support in the `org.springframework.scheduling.support.CronTrigger`. And there is no Quartz support in Spring Integation's poller. However you still can configure a Quartz to call your method for inbound channel adapter and produce a message to the channel.

See more info here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/integration/scheduling.html#scheduling-quartz

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/6705